# How to migrate from sqlite3 to mysql in a rails project?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have completed rails `sample_app`. I used database sqlite3. Now I want to migrate to the mysql for my existing project. I am setting `config/database.yml` as

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: my_db
  username: root  
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

But this technique is not working.

Comment: Could you explain what is not working? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are (hopefully) 2 things you need to do:

1. Remove `sqlite3` from your gemfile and add `mysql2`. Run `bundle install` just in case you never used mysql before with rails.
2. Change the adapter option in your `database.yml` from `sqlite3` to `mysql2`